# Java Servlets: Different kinds of attributes

Tags: java, jsp

Was going through some Java Servlets code.

I found attributes set and retrieved in 3 different ways.

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("var1","value1"); 
req.setAttribute("var2", "value2"); 
getServletContext().setAttribute("var3", "value3");
```

`req` is a variable of type `HttpServletRequest`
I am a little confused as to what is the difference between the three?

Comment: They set the attribute in session, request, or servlet context scope respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.getSession().setAttribute("var1","value1");` - Is a Session Attribute.

`req.setAttribute("var2", "value2");` - Is a Request Attribute.

`getServletContext().setAttribute("var3", "value3");` - Is a Servlet Context Level (an Application) Attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a session attribute, the second one is a request attribute and the third one is an attribute belonging to the `ServletContext`.

If you don't know what the session is and how it differs from the request, you should be studying how HTTP works.

The `ServletContext` is a separate place for the server to keep certain information. You'd more often be getting the attributes from there, rather than setting them.